# Need help creating a Variable length Array

Tags: c, arrays, variables, visual-studio-2015, global

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int row, col;
    printf("Enter rows and columns for your grid");
    scanf_s(" %i%i", &row, &col);
    int Array[row][col];
    return 0;
}
```

This is the example my programming instructor gave us, but I haven't been able to get it to work. My compiler (Visual Studio 2015) keeps giving me the error C2131 "The expression did not evaluate to a constant" Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: If you have a choice of compilers (which you probably do, since it's unlikely your instructor would give you an example that is not supported on the compiler you're supposed use) then use gcc

Comment: MSVC does not support the variable length array.

Comment: Use a modern, standard compliant compiler like gcc or clang.

Answer (score 1):

The VLA is C99 feature, while MSVC supports C89. According to [MSDN documentation for VS 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb1574zs.aspx):

> Variable length arrays are not currently supported in Visual C++.

Comment: Is it true for VS2015?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The link is for VS 2015.

Comment: Hm. So what does that code on the page demonstrate?

Comment: @EugeneSh. use a compiler (like gcc) that does support variable length arrays.  Probably won't be the last time the instructor does something that's different between VS & gcc

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use dynamic memory allocation using [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)

```
int **Array;
Array = malloc(sizeof(int*)*row);
for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
Array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*col);
```